# How to sort two different objects in an NSArray?

Tags: ios, sorting, comparison, nsarray

In my NSArray, I have two types of objects, let's say objects of class A and class B. 
I want to sort these objects, by comparing "startingDate" property of class A to "endingDate" property of class B. And I don't know how to make a comparison based on two different properties of different classes.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blocks are what you want, take a look at this question:
[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)

In the blocks example on that question, just have class A use startingDate and class B use ending date.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but all the block methods were comparing the same type of objects. I mean the block's arguments are id obj1 and id obj2, but then they're cast to the same classes. Now that I have two different types of objects, won't casting be a problem? How will I know which argument to cast to my first class?

Comment: You could check to see what kind of class obj1 and obj2 are by using     [[(obj1/obj2) class] isSubclassofClass: [TargetClass class]] and then dealing with appropriately.

Comment: Of course, but it's kind of messy to do so. I'll go that way if there aren't any better options though, thanks.

Comment: @Jacob use `isKindOfClass` since both objects are probably subclasses of `NSObject`, or they could be subclasses of some other higher level object.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an if/else block and the use of the statement

> [myObject isKindOfClass:[ClassA class]]

Which returns a BOOL

If you'd rather (or in conjunction), Apple recommends using

> [myObject respondsToSelector:@selector(startingDate)]

Which also returns a BOOL.

Blocks aren't really relevant in this situation; You could use this design pattern inside a plain method implementation, blocks, a for/while loop, or anywhere else.